# Is there a way to get rid of this 0 in an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've got a problem with app I'm creating

```
                String[] wspolczynnikiText = wzorFunkcjiText.split("[+x\\s]", 0);
            int[] wspolczynniki = new int[wspolczynnikiText.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < wspolczynnikiText.length; i++) {
                try{
                    wspolczynniki[i] = Integer.parseInt(wspolczynnikiText[i]);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                }
            }
```

So basically it takes user input (sorry for variable names in my native language) and splits it, works good, for example in input "5+4x" it only reads 5, 4 values as it should, but when input is for example "5x+5" it reads 5, 5, 0 values. Is there a way for it to don't happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also anybody has idea why does the 0 take position 2, while it logically should be on position 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting on `+` or `x` (or space). So "5x+5" will be split into `["5", "", "5"]`.

Arrays are zero-initialized. Since the second element cannot be parsed as an int, you end up with `[5,0,5]`.

For input `"5+4x"`, after splitting you have `["5", "4"]`, which will give you `[5,4]` after parsing.

The second argument to split will remove trailing empty strings, see [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)):

> If the limit is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Note that calling `str.split("regex", 0)` is identical to the shorter `str.split("regex")`.

It's probably easier to use an `ArrayList` to append elements and then convert it to an array after the loop (if you really need an array; lists provide more functionality and are easier to use). Using a list also does work for you of keeping track of the current index.

Comment: Actually "5+4x" gives [5, 4] only no 0, and "5x+5" is not [5, 0, 5] but [5, 5, 0], which is even stranger. And thanks for the advice, I'll try ArrayList

Comment: @KrzysztofWawrzyniak - I get `[5, 0, 5]`; not `[5, 5, 0]` see https://ideone.com/AZSI5P (and an Exception [being ignored in original code])